# Text file containing empty spaces in c++!

Tags: c++

I have a problem with reading a txt file of the following form:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1    f f   f   f f  
 2  f     f f   f f f
 3  f f   f   f f
 4  f f   f       f f 
 5      f   f f     f
```

where: (1,2,3,,,,,) are indeces, f's are data of type double.
I have tried to read the contents using matrix notation i.e. tab[i][j]; i've succeeded to do it when my file doesn't contain empty, but when it does have emty spaces as shown above, data is displayed randomly and i don't understand anything of it.

So, can anyone enlighten me please??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use raw data reading functions, such as `istream.get()` or `istream.read()`, instead of the extraction operator (`>>`), because the extraction operator removes whitespace.

`std::getline(istream&, string&)` is also a good choice, because it preserves spaces.

Comment: mmmmm, okey, that's no big deal, i've used "noskipws" and I've read the entire text as it is.
but when i try to retrieve the 2 row for exemple i get a messy data, i've a problem in indexing and retrieving the right data,,,,

Comment: @NadCo: `noskipws` will prevent stripping out leading whitespace, but it doesn't change the behavior where the first space character ends a string.  `std::getline` seems much more appropriate for your task.

Answer (score 0):

If the data contains optional values each separated by (always) a single space character, I would try the string-reading approach given in the answer by @BenVoigt, then use a `split` function (there are many examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere), telling it NOT to remove empty values.  This is the best way I can think of to deal with the multiple `[Space]` characters next to each other.

Thus if you have read a line of text like this:

```
[Space][Space]1.2[Space]3.4[Space]
```

You'll end up with an array (or vector or whatever) that contains:

```
"" (Empty string)
""
"1.2"
"3.4"
""
```

...which I think is what you're looking for.